# PHP `exec()` doesn't work if run by Cron

Tags: php, centos, cron, centos7

I have a PHP script that is being called every minute by crontab like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/watchdog/watchdogExec.php
```

The script executes a number of other PHP scripts and passes a variable like so:

```
$ccmd = "nohup sudo /usr/bin/php watchdog.php " . $var . " &";
exec($ccmd);
```

When called from a browser, **watchdogExec.php** runs fine and does its job. However when I added the cronjob, the script is not working and is spamming mails with the following error:

```
No entry for terminal type "unknown";
using dumb terminal settings.
```

This error appears the same number of times `exec()` is called, so I figured that must be the issue. I searched and read about cronjob not running commands in a terminal, and I tried setting the environment in the crontask, but it did not help. Apparently PHP is printing that error, but I haven't found anything in their documentation about it.

```
* * * * *  /usr/bin/env TERM=xterm /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/watchdog/watchdogExec.php
```

I am running CentOS 7.

Edit:

Searched some more and found out about PHP environment variables. Someone fixed a similar problem by adding the following in their PHP script. However this is not fixing my problem, it only stops the mail spam. The script is still not working.

```
putenv('SHELL=/bin/bash');
putenv('TERM=xterm');
```

Comment: Add debug output to your script, **it's not working** is to vague...

Comment: What does `$var` equal in code? (look for a line starting with `$var=`)

Comment: @Mike it's unrelated, it's an integer from a database. The script runs when called from a browser, it's the lack of a terminal in cron that's causing this.

Comment: ensure if your 'watchdog.php' is being called at all. just log something in the very first line to say /tmp/watchdog.log. dump the $var there too. this should get you general direction to solution. post the results there, maybe I can help further.

Comment: @OlegShemetov it's not being ran, it should output some data to a database if it ran but it's not. The `No entry...` error is being printed after `exec()` is called and the operation fails.

Comment: what happens when you call /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/watchdog/watchdogExec.php directly from console (not browser)? from the same user that owns that crontab.

Comment: @OlegShemetov it runs fine. Everything is under root, no users.

Comment: I can only suggest logging both stdout and stderr streams from cron call (using  2>&1 at the end of your call) to some log file like /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/watchdog/watchdogExec.php > /tmp/watchdog.log 2>&1. see if there's something else other than your terminal error. turn on php error reporting and display_errors.

Comment: @OlegShemetov I'm trying to get the answer posted to work, it seems like a good idea, but for some reason the shell script keeps printing file not found even if I run it from the terminal. There won't be a real solution to this problem except getting cron to somehow run the PHP from a real terminal environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using full paths in your exec statement too? Also try adding the TERM environment variable:

```
$ccmd = "nohup /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/env TERM=xterm /usr/bin/php watchdog.php " . $var . " &";
```

Comment: Holy crap it worked. also changed `nohup` to `/usr/bin/nohup`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with a 'shell script wrapper'. I add a file `phpcron.sh` with

```
#!/bin/bash   
php -f filename.php
```

and add this to crontab.

```
* * * * * /var/www/phpcron.sh
```

Comment: Tried it that way, it now mails a simple `: No such file or directory`. My script is `#!/bin/bash   
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/watchdog/watchdogExec.php`

Comment: I managed to get it working by adding a `bash` before the path to the script. However the `No entry... ` error still persists.