# PHP `exec()` doesn't work if run by a process initiated from Cron

Tags: php, bash, shell, cron

I have a Beanstalk MQ where I put task to create APK, and a consumer named AppBuilder.php, which reads messages from Beanstalk MQ, and then `exec` the command which creates the App (android app).

The AppBuilder.php is run from the crontab. the process is

1. Crontab runs a health-check.sh shell script
2. health-check.sh runs AppBuilder.php in background
3. AppBuilder.php calls `exec` to create the process

Following is the relevant code snippet(s) from each file:

Root crontab is like so:

```
* * * * * /opt/cron/health-check/health-check.sh
```

health-check.sh is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/sbin/

#HEALTH CHECK FOR AppBuilder Daemon
if (( $(ps -ef | grep "[A]ppBuilder" | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
echo "AppBuilder is Running" 
else
echo "AppBuilder is Stopped, attempting to restart" 
$PHP_CMD /opt/appbuilder/AppBuilder.php &
if pgrep "AppBuilder" > /dev/null
then
echo "AppBuilder is now Running"
else
echo "AppBuilder is still not Running"
fi
fi
```

AppBuilder.php has following exec command:

> exec('sudo sh /var/www/cgi-bin/appbuilder/oneClickApk.sh &', $output, $resultCode);

If I run the AppBuilder.php directly, things work fine. However, from cron, it does not.

I've followed [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054223/php-exec-doesnt-work-if-run-by-cron?rq=1), and modified the exec command to the following:

> exec('/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/env TERM=xterm /bin/sh /var/www/cgi-bin/appbuilder/oneClickApk.sh &', $output, $resultCode);

However, still things fail. Any clues where this may be going wrong? I've spend a lot of time digging the forums, none helping. Please help!

EDIT 1:

The crontab runs, AppBuilder.php gets initialized, but after exec command, I could not see the oneClickApk.sh in process list

EDIT 2:

I changed the crontab from root to ec2-user, as suggested in comments: Still the process does not run.

Comment: Try adding `/bin/sh`, (eg. `/bin/sh /opt/cron/health-check/health-check.sh`)...

Comment: Does not work. Can you tell me why you suggested that?

Comment: Because `/opt/cron/health-check/health-check.sh` is not a valid command (try it, and it will likely return command not found). Cron doesn't know what to do without a valid command. So putting `/bin/sh`, `sh` or even doing `./opt/cron/health-check/health-check.sh` should run the command properly.

Comment: Its executable, hence it was working

ls -la /opt/cron/health-check/health-check.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 4346 Apr 17 12:11 /opt/cron/health-check/health-check.sh

Comment: That's fine, but it still cannot be executed without putting a command in front of it generally.

Comment: Ok. But that doesnt seem to be the problem. Can you check if the exact same thing runs on your machine?

Comment: If the crontab executes then yes, it's likely something else like your command. Running something with sudo is a very bad idea. You should likely set the permissions to be run with your web user and group.

Comment: I've moved crontab entry to run health-check.sh from root to ec2-user, things still dont work!

Comment: @l'L'l - that is the purpose of the shebang at the start of the script.  If the script is called directly, then it will translate it to `<shebang> command`, in this case `/bin/bash /opt/cron/health-check/health-check.sh`

Comment: @AlexStiff What gave you the idea that is what is being done here? The OP is attempting to execute the health-check.sh from the crontab!

Answer (score 0):

Just following your first approach like below. But to fix the issue you have to do the following.

1. Check your cron-tab entry whether properly set or not.
2. In cron-tab provide full path to your executable
3. Check whether cron-tab user account has proper setting to execute `sudo`
4. Check whether cron-tab account has proper permission to execute your PHP application as well as your shell script. If not add the account into the proper group so that it can run both the PHP and shell script.

   ```
   exec('sudo sh /var/www/cgi-bin/appbuilder/oneClickApk.sh &', $output, $resultCode);
   ```

Use above command its seems OK.

In you shell script put a wait command and check whether it is working fine or not. Just add only below two lines without any `if` condition first. If working then you need to check your if condition why they are not satisfying as per your requirement.

```
$PHP_CMD /opt/appbuilder/AppBuilder.php &
while (( $(ps -ef | grep "[h]ealth-check.sh" | wc -l) <= 0 ))
do
       sleep 5
done
sleep 30
```

Comment: Why would running from shell the AppBuilder.php work, but the same thing from crontab not (where now, crontab is running from same linux user - ec2-user)?

Comment: As I said in my answer did you check whether you have provided full path like `/app/php/AppBuilder.php`?

Comment: full path like that where?

Comment: I have modified my answer. Please see the last option and do a test first.

Comment: With that "wait", it works. However, the moment i stop the newly created script which has the wait, the exec process stops too

Comment: What is the solution to this Abhijit?

Comment: instead of wait put a sleep 20 and check.

Comment: You shell script is the parent process so if you kill it, it will kill the PHP process as well. So put a long sleep like mention above comment and try.

Comment: But PHP process is not killed when shell script is killed. Instead, the exec command process gets killed

Comment: because it killed the wait command as well. Did you try with sleep?

Comment: It works with sleep, even after the sleep is over and the script ends. Magic! Why @Abhijeet? Whats the magic here?

Comment: But now, what change should I do? In the original files (health-check/crontab/AppBuilder.php)?

Comment: Just fyi, changing health-check.sh to include a sleep 20 at its bottom does not do anything. The exec processes are still not working :(

Comment: The magic is before the exe command starts your shell script exit and hence it can not start properly as you are running it on background mode. If you remove the `&` you don't even need to do anything.  Just put a sleep 10 in your original file.

Comment: What as per you would be the right way to do it? I'm still not entirely sure what the fix would be?

Comment: Just add sleep just below `$PHP_CMD /opt/appbuilder/AppBuilder.php &` also check whether  and check whether its prints `echo "AppBuilder is Stopped, attempting to restart" `

Comment: Abhijit, I did add sleep but it still does not work. My fear is that the actual exec command runs after the sleep has elapsed, since that task from MQ can be returned at random time.

Comment: increate the sleep to 60 and check. Can you see this statement `"AppBuilder is Stopped, attempting to restart"` Is it really execute `$PHP_CMD /opt/appbuilder/AppBuilder.php &` line or not?

Comment: Abhijeet, if the MQ receives the message an hour after the AppBuilder.php process has started from health-check.sh, how would a sleep of 60 seconds help? What is solution to that?

Comment: Yes I did see the statement AppBuilder is Stopped, attempting to restat

Comment: Just put a while loop and check for exec process is start or not if started sleep for a minutes and break the loop.

Comment: @Jamboree, I have modified my answer. Just follow the last part. And let me know.